# Need to control the windows logon process

Tags: windows, vb6, winlogon

I have an application I wrote in VB6 and it needs to run right after the user logs in but before the desktop actually loads. Why you ask, well I'll tell you. The VB app asks the user for some information that is validated against an external database. if the validation fails then the user should not be allowed to login, hence the VB app forces a logout. I've read some articles about msGina.dll and the logon process but I still am not finding a viable solution. any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you'd want to write your own GINA provider to modify the login mechanism in Windows. Understand, however, that this is a serious undertaking, will require you to write your code in C/C++ and you have to be very, VERY careful about how you build it so as to not open-up several backdoors and vulnerabilities and so that you don't destabilize the rest of Windows.

Your VB6 app is NOT the way to go in this scenario for a multitude of reasons, not least of which are the fact that it's pretty trivial to intercept and bypass your security mechanism entirely.

Buildng a login mechanism seems like a piece of cake until you REALLY start digging into how to build one that's rock solid and bomb-proof. I know this because I once lead a team building a custom GINA for a European government's secure desktops!

If you're certain you DO want to go build a custom GINA, then take a look at these overview articles:

[Customizing GINA, Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx)

[Customizing GINA, Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163786.aspx)

Comment: Keep in mind this only works for Windows XP.  Windows Vista and later have a different mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

A GINA is one option, but only for Windows XP.  The equivalent for Windows Vista and later is a [credential provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

As an alternative, you can change the initial user process by changing the Userinit value in this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

If you do this, make sure your application launches userinit when it is done, or the user's shell won't be started.  Note that this will not prevent knowledgeable users from bypassing your application, at least not without further steps.

A [credential manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374792%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can interact with the user during the logon process, but I don't believe it provides any direct way of rejecting the logon.  It might be possible to hack something together but I wouldn't recommend it.

I believe a [group policy client-side extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is capable of rejecting a user logon, but I'm not familiar with this technology.

Comment: I was looking into replacing the Shell for the user with the app I need them to interact with. My thought here is that if the cancel the app for any reason they get logged out. If they pass the credentials test then they can continue with loading the desktop. Which registry value is better to use 'Shell' or 'Userinit'

Comment: Probably userinit, but I suggest you experiment.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange approach to security, you could take a look at the "Autoexec.bat" file although I haven't messed around with this myself. Either way I suspect the user could probably "End Task" your VB6 app from the task manager and head about their merry way.